# Transitive relation on set [1,2,3] (exercise question)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Why $$P=[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1)]$$
Is not a transitive relation even though it meets all requirements for it.

** a relation R on a set X is transitive if, for all elements a, b, c in X, whenever R relates a to b and b to c, then R also relates a to c. **

Comment: $(3,1), (1,2) \in P \implies (3,2) \in P \quad$ if $P$ is transitive.

Comment: I always found it helpful to draw the picture out on an $xy$ plane, you can see immediately Symmetry and Reflexivity, and it usually helps with Transitivity. Otherwise, it is as @PedroSilva said.

Comment: Igor thanks .how to identify them after drawing the picture

Comment: If a relation on S  is reflexive , for all elment $a$ belonging to S , you will have a point (a,a)  ( that is, a point on the $y=x$ line). If it is ymmetric for every point (a,b) in R, you will have a symmetric point (b,a) ; that is pairs with different elements are distributed symmetrically below and above the $y=x$ line.